# Can you tell me how to use a timer in Rust?

Tags: rust, timer

Can you tell me how to use a timer in Rust? I need it to close after a certain time after entering the loop, use the break.

I used this, but it is necessary not after the start, but after entering the cycle.

```
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

fn main() {
    let seconds = Duration::from_secs(5);  

    let start = Instant::now();
    loop {
       

        if Instant::now() - start >= seconds { 
            return;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.rs/timer/latest/timer/struct.Timer.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SystemTime::now()`.

An example from [SystemTime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html) docs:

```rust
use std::time::{Duration, SystemTime};
use std::thread::sleep;

fn main() {
   let now = SystemTime::now();

   // we sleep for 2 seconds
   sleep(Duration::new(2, 0));
   match now.elapsed() {
       Ok(elapsed) => {
           // it prints '2'
           println!("{}", elapsed.as_secs());
       }
       Err(e) => {
           // an error occurred!
           println!("Error: {e:?}");
       }
   }
}
```

And your code could look like this

```
use std::time::{Duration, SystemTime};

fn main() {
    let seconds = Duration::from_secs(5);

    let start = SystemTime::now();
    loop {
        // Делаем что-то.
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::new(2, 0));

        match start.elapsed() {
            Ok(elapsed) if elapsed > seconds => {
                return;
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is good, but I need to close the loop, not the whole code.

Comment: @WiktorKazmerchuk, you wrote `return` in your code sample, and returning from `main` closes the program. To close the loop, you need to use `break` instead.

Answer (score 3):

> I need it to close after a certain time after entering the loop, use the break.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that. But if you want to pause the execution of your program inside each loop iteration for five seconds, there is the [`thread::sleep`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) function you can use like this:

```rust
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let seconds = Duration::from_secs(5);  
    
    let start = Instant::now();
    loop {
        thread::sleep(seconds.clone()); // waits 5 seconds
        
        assert!(Instant::now() - start >= seconds);
        
        return;
    }
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b2f6b1ff8975b3c113ef52d36d067665)

Answer (score 1):

To measure time in Rust, you need `Instant`’s method called `elapsed` that returns `Duration`, which has several methods for conversion to seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds.

Example:

```rust
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};

let start = Instant::now();

while start.elapsed().as_secs() < 5 {
    // your code
}
```